# sql simple join but multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to do a simple join between 2 tables but it returns an error

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2
ON ID.tbl1=login.tbl2
```

> The multi-part identifier "ID.tbl1" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "ID.tbl2" could not be bound.

Comment: Wrong order, should be `tbl1.id` etc

Comment: The table aliases goes first:  `tbl1.id`.

Comment: I also would like my SELECT to return only tbl1 (and not  tbl2 + tbl1.GID)

Comment: Try `SELECT tbl1.GID FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.ID=tbl2.ID`